# C# & EF 4 - Update related object in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection

My classes (and tables):

```
class A {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual C CField {get; set;}
}

class B {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}

    public virtual C CField {get; set;}
}

class C {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

class D {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}

    public virtual A AField {get; set;}
    public virtual B BField {get; set;}
}
```

I need update my *D* object. I use dependency injection so I can use repositories in controller:

```
A aObj = aService.GetAById(id);
B bObj = bService.GetBByName(name);
D dObj = new D()
{
    Title = "MyTitle",
    AField = aObj,
    BField = bObj
};
dService.Update(dObj);
```

In each class repository I just create context as private field:

```
private MyContext db = new MyContext();
```

and I use it in every method like:

```
var model = db.A.Where(x=>x.Id == id);
return model;
```

But it can't work because both classes *A* and *B* has field with *C* class so I still got excepted: **An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker** when I call `dService.Update(dObj)` (second listing).
I found that I should detach context in every method in each repositroy like this:

```
var model = db.A.Where(x=>x.Id == id);
db.Entry(model).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
return model;
```

Exception was gone but now CField in `aObj` and `bObj` is always null and `dObj.BField` is not updated.

How can I fix that and what I'm doing wrong? I lost a few days for finding out what I should do: I even try remove private context field in repositories and in every method just use `using(var db = new MyContext())` but then exception "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker" is back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix entities from different contexts in EF. Use ids instead.

Update models:

```
class A {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int CFieldId {get; set;}
    public virtual C CField {get; set;}
}

class B {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public int CFieldId {get; set;}
    public virtual C CField {get; set;}
}

class C {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

class D {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public int AFieldId {get; set;}
    public int BFieldId {get; set;}
    public virtual A AField {get; set;}
    public virtual B BField {get; set;}
}
```

And in controller:

```
A aObj = aService.GetAById(id);
B bObj = bService.GetBByName(name);
D dObj = new D()
{
    Title = "MyTitle",
    AFieldId = aObj.Id,
    BFieldId = bObj.Id
};
dService.Update(dObj);
```

Comment: You already have the Id of `A` so you don't need to run the query `aService.GetAById(id)`

Comment: @Szel: let me kiss you! :D Work like a charm, thanks!